# Changing mysql column using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have an assignment where I have to update a column from my mysql by using Java. I've already established connection etc...

I have a table with 4 columns : **ID, ProductName, Price and Quantity**

I want to be able to change the quantity for only ONE product by button click on a Java application. **Example:**

```
ID|ProductName|Price|Quantity
_____________________________
1 |  Water    | 20  |30

2 |  Soda     | 25  |30

3 |  Juice    | 25  |30
```

On a button click I want to ONLY change the quantity of Soda to 29, and if I press the button again it shall go down to 28, while Water and Juice will remain with 30. How do I do this in Java using JButton and selecting this single product (and not all the quantities)..?

**EDIT :** After the two clicks it should look like this :

```
ID|ProductName|Price|Quantity
_____________________________
1 |  Water    | 20  |30

2 |  Soda     | 25  |28

3 |  Juice    | 25  |30
```

** The requested code:

```
   public void updateMethod(){
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String userName = "root";
        String passWord = "";
        String dataBase = "database";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dataBase, userName, passWord);
        if (!conn.isClosed())
        {
            Statement s = conn.createStatement ( );
            s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM `database`.Drinks");
            String query = "UPDATE Drinks SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE productName = 'Soda' and quantity > 0";
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   //This one did not work.. pstmt.setString(1, "Soda");
            int result = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet ( );
            while (rs.next()) // loop through rows of result set
            {
                int DrinkID = rs.getInt(1);
                String productName = rs.getString(2);
                int price = rs.getInt(3);
                int quantity = rs.getInt(4);

                System.out.println ("ID: " + DrinkID + "\t" + "Product: " + productName + " " + "Price: " + price + " " + "Quantity: " + quantity);
            }
            rs.close(); // close result set
            s.close(); // close statement
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // If we don't have a error, close the connection!
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't really try that much as I have no clue how to. I have established connection and I can print all the information out in the console without problem. I just want to change this one information on a button click from my JFrame

Comment: Run an approriate `update` statement through JDBC: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Have you managed to add the JButton to your JFrame?  If so, have you managed to add an ActionListener to respond to button click events?  If so, is your actionPerformed method   executing an UPDATE statement on your MySQL connection?  Is the UPDATE statement failing?  Are there any exceptions?

Comment: I have a JButton inside my JFrame, and I also I have added actionListener (however I do not know whether I have done this correctly). Shall my mysql code in eclipse (the connection etc.) stay inside my actionPerformed method so that it may run again and again when clicking on button thus update?

Answer (score 0):

You would execute your sql based on the product name:

```
UPDATE product_table
SET Quantity = Quantity - 1
WHERE ProductName = 'Soda'
and Quantity > 0
```

This will decrement the value of the quantity by 1.

Heres a guide on how to execute sql queries in java - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

**EDIT: Adding code to perform the update query from above:**

```
String query = "UPDATE product_table SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE ProductName = ? and Quantity > 0";

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, "Soda");

int result = pstmt.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
```

**EDIT: Adding full sample code**

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    String userName = "root";
    String passWord = "";
    String dataBase = "database";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dataBase, userName, passWord);
}

public void print() {

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = getConnection();

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `database`.Drinks");

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int DrinkID = rs.getInt(1);
            String productName = rs.getString(2);
            int price = rs.getInt(3);
            int quantity = rs.getInt(4);

            System.out.println("ID: " + DrinkID + "\t" + "Product: " + productName + " " + "Price: " + price + " " + "Quantity: " + quantity);

        }
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If we don't have a error, close the connection!
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
}

public void update() {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = getConnection();

        String query = "UPDATE Drinks SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE productName = ? and quantity > 0";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, "Soda");

        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // If we don't have a error, close the connection!
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds very correct. However, what shall I exactly write? When you say 'sql based', does that mean that I have to use the 'Statement' command and from there the .executeUpdate() method?

Comment: Thanks alot! This seemes to work the database is being updated when I refresh my table using mysql workbench. But here is a problem and that is when I print out the information it does not decrease in the console but as for the database the quantity is decreased. How do I solve this one?

Comment: My system out is in a while loop with rs.next, may be that?

Comment: What exactly are you printing out? Is it from a list that was populated before the updates were made to the table? Or is it after?

Comment: I have done this; int ID = rs.getInt(1); String productName = rs.getString(2); etc.... Rs is ResultSet. Then I print everything out. The update code are just above all these.

Comment: But when I look at my mysql workbench, the quantity is still the same but when I update the table it changes. Maybe eclipse gets the information of the non-updated (or rather non-refreshed) table. I think that is the problem.. It has to get the information from the table that has been refreshed, but whether that is possible from eclipse - I have no clue.

Comment: Sorry for being that late. Please look at my question again as my code is now posted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are executing your SELECT before the UPDATE, you need to do the update first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I put the SELECT under conn.commit() but unfortunately, it only updates first time I click the button. So it will go from 20 to 19 for instance, but it won't go down to 18 if I click once more.

Comment: @user3161041 I have updated my answer with full sample code for what you're looking. I have split the `print()` and `update()` methods out for simplicity. Call `update()` when you want to decrease the value, then call `print()` to print out the values from the database

Comment: When I use this one pstmt.setString(1, "Soda"); it gives me this error: Exception: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). I have no clue why. When I remove this command then it is as before; it works on first click but not on second.

Comment: Are you leaving the question mark ? in the query string? It is how you indicate a parameter and will be replaced by Soda when  pstmt.setString(1, "Soda"); is called

Comment: Okay I put question mark instead as you've had done and it does not give me that error any longer. But still it only works first click where it decreases with one. When I click the button again it prints the same out (for instance it goes from 20 to 19, but then it is stuck at 19 no matter how many times you press the button). Though it updates in my mysql workbench when I re-select the table.